# Xen: 'this operation cannot be performed' (virtual disk not found) error?

Tags: xen

When trying to start a VM:

```
This operation cannot be completed because the specified virtual disk cannot be found
```

How do I work around this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Xen 6.2 make sure that the VM doesn't have a 'disk' in the 'DVD'. Switch it to `<empty>` and try the (re)start again.

Comment: Just to be clear, make sure the DVD selection says `<empty>` - a completely blank line is wrong!